# Java Search String for explicit words

Tags: java, string, contains

I'm working on a project that takes in a string, and it creates a file with the string name, But I want it to ban certain words. how would I do this?

```
String fname = scanner(System.in);
//check if it contains explicit words
if (fname.contains("THE BAD WORD HERE")) {
    System.out.println(fname + " contains inappropriate words and is not accepted.");
} else {
    System.out.println(fname + " is all good");
    //create file
    createFile(fname);
}
```

do I have to use a for loop and go through every char? or is there a simpler way? please help.

Comment: java does not have a method `contians`.I hope you meant `contains`

Comment: Sorry I meant `contains`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would loop through every "Bad word" and look to see if the String contained the word. If so, you set a flag.

For example:

```
String[] badWords = new String[5]; 
//set all of you bad words
String fname = scanner(System.in);
//check if it contains explicit words
boolean containsBadWord = false;
for(String badWord : badWords){
    if (fname.contains(badWord)) {
        containsBadWord = true;
        break;
    } 
}
if(containsBadWord){
    System.out.println(fname + " contains inappropriate words and is not accepted.");
}
else {
    System.out.println(fname + " is all good");
    //create file
    createFile(fname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a Set of bad words...

The problem with this is keeping track of every inappropriate word though. A simpler solution would probably be to remove all vowels, as that would not require a massive set of inappropriate words -- what if you accidentally allow a word that is inappropriate in French or some other language for example?

Anyway, here is a HashSet based solution:

```
Set<String> badWords = new HashSet<String>();
badWords.add("f*ck");
badWords.add("sh*t");
... etc
```

Of course you'll want to perform case insensitive compare so:

```
boolean hasBadWord(String filename, Set<String> badWords) {
    String filenameLower = filename.toLowerCase();
    for(String badWord : badWords) {
        if( filenameLower.contains(badWord) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

more on sets can be found here: [java Sets documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html)